What is the relatively easiest way to create an entity relationship diagram from a Microsoft SQL Script?
I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio v18.11.1. I realize I do not have the DB Diagrams functionality that other versions have had.
What is my best option? I was hoping to use a tool that could read through my entire script and plot out the tables (and ideally relationships), but it looks like at best I am going to have the table blocks created for me in the ER diagram and I will have to manually connect the tables in the diagram.
Is there any way around that? Thanks for any and all advice.

Why not install a newer version of SSMS which supports diagrams? The current version (20.2.30.0) supports diagrams and I believe can be installed along side of your older version if needed.

@DanGuzman i've downloaded that, but am unaware where the diagram functionality is.
